# How to Validate HTML, CSS and JS in Eclipse IDE

Tags: javascript, html, css, eclipse, validation

I am using eclipse with WTP plugin for writing HTML, CSS and JS code. For validating pages I need to visit w3c website. Is it possible to configure eclipse in a way that offline validation is possible within eclipse. If so, kindly mention in detail as I am new to eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the explorer window (that lists all your files and folders) highlight the files you want to validate, right click and select Validate. The warnings and errors can be seen in the Problems pane (Window -> Show View -> Problems).

The Eclipse website has a walkthrough on validation: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/XMLValidation/XMLValidationTutorial.html